# MOQ Unit testing error. Expected invocation on the mock once, but was 0 times

Tags: c#, .net, moq

I know this question has been asked on here before, but I am very confused as to why this test is failing. Here is the test I am running:

```
    public void SubmitWebservicePurchaseOrder_Calls_addQuickAddItemListToPO()
    {
        var input = new PurchaseOrderWebserviceSubmitDTO();
        _service.SubmitWebservicePurchaseOrder(input);

        var dict = It.IsAny<Dictionary<long, QuickAddOrCSVLineItem>>();
        _purchaseOrderMock.Verify(x => x.addQuickAddItemListToPO(It.IsAny<long>(), It.Is<bool>(y => y == false), ref dict), Times.Once);
    }
```

And Here is what the error says:

```
Result Message: 
Moq.MockException : 
Expected invocation on the mock once, but was 0 times: x => x.addQuickAddItemListToPO(It.IsAny<Int64>(), It.Is<Boolean>(y => y == False), .dict)
No setups configured.

Performed invocations:
IPurchaseOrders.CreateNewPO(OMS.DataLayer.poHeader)
IPurchaseOrders.addQuickAddItemListToPO(0, False, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.Int64,OMS.DataServices.QuickAddOrCSVLineItem])
IPurchaseOrders.GetPOHeaderInfoWithUserToken(0, 00000000, 00000000)
```

The function `SubmitWebservicePurchaseOrder` is definitely calling `addQuickAddItemListToPO`, yet I am still getting this error... Anyone know why? I havn't worked much with MOQ before and am not really sure how to debug...

Comment: Can you make a [mre]?

Comment: Show us the code where you are attempting to set the Mock up since this states no setup provided. You should be creating a new mock object first against the interface. then you set any input values.

Comment: Need to see the setup for your mock and the code under test, otherwise we cant give you any more information than the error message does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the issue, the `ref` parameter on `addQuickAddItemListToPO` was not getting passed in correctly/was getting read as null. Once I updated my MOQ library and changed the parameter to `ref It.Ref<Dictionary<long, QuickAddOrCSVLineItem>>.IsAny`, the test passed.

And sorry for not posting more code guys, i figured what i posted was enough for someone out there to help.

Answer (score 0):

The verify checks that a Mocked Function has been called, the Moq function needs setting up as test for being called.
You look to be attempting to test if the implemented function on X is being called.